# Naming issue with Perl Sub::Override

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I am using the module [Sub::Override](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub%3a%3aOverride) to mock a subroutine during testing. I am actually testing a subroutine named sub_a. sub_a is calling another subroutine sub_b to do some work. sub_b is actually executing some commands over the ssh connection which I want to mock in my testing mode. So I am using sub::override to mock sub_b.

```
sub_a{
 ...
 sub_b(arg1, arg2)
}
```

In my test code I am overriding it like this

```
my $override_sshCommand = override_sub( 'package::filename::sub_b', sub ($$) { return "success"; }, undef );
```

In the above code if sub_b and sub_a are in the same class then the override is successful. Otherwise the override does not work.
I can fix this issue by using the fully qualified name of sub_b when calling from sub_a

```
sub_a{
 ...
 package::filename::sub_b(arg1, arg2);
}
```

The above code fixes the issue and the override is successful. But I don't want to do it like this, as I don't own that code and also it looks ugly. Is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume `sub_b` is imported by the package that contains `sub_a`?

You're changing the sub to which the name `package_of_sub_b::sub_b` refers.

You're not changing the sub to which the name `package_of_sub_a::sub_b` refers.

If the second name you're resolving, so you need to override the `sub_b` in the package that contains `sub_a`.

```
override_sub( 'package_of_sub_a::sub_b', ... );
```

Comment: yes sub_b was imported by the package that contains sub_a, and calling it like you mentioned, solved the problem, Thanks :)